# getRecord returns 'undefined' for Salesforce Mobile App

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, salesforce-mobile-app, barcode

I have created a Barcode Scanning LWC App, from salesforce continuous barcode scanning documentation. I have wrapped it in an AURA component and placed it on standard 'Order' object layout for mobile. The scanning works perfectly, however I tried getting the order record id from which it is scanned, but somehow *@api recordId* for *getRecord()* always returns 'undefined' (have added api decorator in import).

The only reason I could think was if the context of the component might not be set correct as it is mobile, so I added pretty much all the context's I could think off, still no luck, kindly help:

Here is my meta.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
        </targetConfig>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <supportedFormFactors>
                <supportedFormFactor type="Large" />
                <supportedFormFactor type="Small" />
            </supportedFormFactors>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: have you passed the record id from aura to lwc?

Comment: Apologies for the late response, got involved ... thank you @sanket, I think I overlooked that part. Cheers!!!